# Unable to play videos after converting from Netbook 10.04 to Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: lubuntu, video

On my HP mini, I converted from my Netbook 10.04 (frown) to Lubuntu 14.04. I also installed lubuntu-restricted-extras and addons and I cannot play videos. I've tried VLC, changing the video output to X11 as suggested by other blogs but it still won't play the videos. These videos are formatted in avi mkv and h264. I've taken the videos to another computer that is running Ubuntu 14.04 and it is playing them just fine.

An extreme option, in lieu of converting, would a fresh install of Lubuntu be on the plate or is there another less invasive option to play videos?

laserman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some packages may be incompatible with each other.

Please try reinstalling vlc and dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall vlc
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-restricted-extras
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Comment: That worked part of the way. It plays the first frame but nothing else. The timer at the bottom in VLC shows its playing but it is still on the first frame. One other note. It now plays .avi files in Gnome Player but not VLC.

Comment: Hi Laserman, please get us some verbose output here. Please play your video from terminal, by running: `vlc -v video.mkv` and then share some errors you may get (probably in red)

Comment: It must have been slow to catch up. Maybe after a reboot, things were aligned. I initiated the command above like you said and the video played. The initial suggestion you made with reinstalling the software must have corrected the problem from the start. VLC is working fine along with Gnome Player. All problems have been corrected. Thanks @qugu!